What is the X-Vector DNN Purpose?
So I've seen and use the implementation of an X-Vector DNN but I'm not quite sure how I should think of it. Is it perhaps similar to 'Skip-gram'? In the sense of, Skip-gram trains a binary classifier with logistic regression, so input is a token and output are probabilities to context that the model associates with that token. It's self-supervised because you can just use the n-grams to get the 'correct' context, no manual labelling required. Note, we actually do not care about these probabilities, we never use them directly. They are relevant for the training and gradient descent to work but the only thing we care about are the parameters, which we then turn into our embeddings per token.
Here with X-vectors, it starts with MFCCs just like GMMs, then they pass through various layers with each layer trying to capture some kind of context. The output is still a vector of probabilities that I assume is used for speaker classification. However, the model allows you to 'extract' an embedding for a given input before it is passed to the last layers and softmax. You can then extract for each input an embedding and use cosine similarity as a metric for also speaker verification?
So is the actual classifier that outputs probabilities not important/not used like skip-gram or does the X-vector model achieve two things at the same time?
